# How to trigger a command after named pipe closes?

Tags: shell-script, background-process, signals, fifo, trap

How can I execute some command after the named pipe has been readout in other end. I was trying to use `trap`. But nothing happens. My script is something like below.

```
#!/bin/sh

cleanup()
{
  echo "Caught Signal ... cleaning up the background process."
}

trap cleanup PIPE

if [ ! -p "/tmp/mysqld.init" ]; then
    mkfifo /tmp/mysqld.init
fi

echo  "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;" > /tmp/mysqld.init &

exec mysqld --init-file="/tmp/mysqld.init"
```

Note: This is my docker image's entrypoint script and `exec` is necessary in my case.

Comment: If the exec is successful, the shell will no longer exist, so there's no way for the shell to write to a closed pipe and no way the trap body would run. What do you want to do after the pipe has been read?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by shell will no longer exist. But in my case as I am creating a docker image `mysqld` runs as pid 1 for ever. I just want to close the child/background process after the pipe has been read.